# My flutter app doesn't connect to the internet when is on private network (vpn)

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm making an App for my company and I need it to work on a private network (VPN) but when I'm on VPN it doesn't work, tried to print the result witch should give me a json instead gives me this "

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid
>   credentials.

", but if I change the URL to "[https://randomuser.me/api/?results=15][1]" I get the data with no problem.
I tried to check connectivity when I'm on VPN and gives me result none.

```
...
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var _connection = 'Unknown';
  Connectivity connectivity;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;

  String url = 'myUrl';
  List data;

  Future<String> makeRequest() async {
    var response = await http
        .post(url, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'});

  print('________________________________________________________________________^^^^ '+ response.body );
    setState(() {
      var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
      //data = extractdata;
      //print( data[0]["name"]["first"]);
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectivity = new Connectivity();
    subscription = connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen( (ConnectivityResult result){print('RESULT');print(result);});
    this.makeRequest();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
...
```

this is the console result

````
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SM J500FN...
Restarted application in 5 173ms.
I/flutter (16502): RESULT
I/flutter (16502): ConnectivityResult.none
I/flutter (16502): ________________________________________________________________________^^^^ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
I/flutter (16502): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
I/flutter (16502): <head>
I/flutter (16502): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
I/flutter (16502): <title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
I/flutter (16502): <style type="text/css">
I/flutter (16502): <!--
I/flutter (16502): body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
I/flutter (16502): fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
I/flutter (16502): h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
I/flutter (16502): h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
I/flutter (16502): h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
I/flutter (16502): #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
I/flutter (16502): background-color:#555555;}
I/flutter (16502): #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
I/flutter (16502): .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
I/flutter (16502): -->
I/flutter (16502): </style>
I/flutter (16502): </head>
I/flutter (16502): <body
E/flutter (16502): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (16502): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org...
E/flutter (16502): ^
E/flutter (16502): 
E/flutter (16502): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1357:5)
E/flutter (16502): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1253:9)
E/flutter (16502): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:921:22)
E/flutter (16502): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:29:10)
E/flutter (16502): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:491:36)
E/flutter (16502): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:149:41)
E/flutter (16502): #6      _MyHomePageState.makeRequest.<anonymous closure> (package:doi_report/homepage.dart:30:30)
E/flutter (16502): #7      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1122:30)
E/flutter (16502): #8      _MyHomePageState.makeRequest (package:doi_report/homepage.dart:29:5)
E/flutter (16502): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16502): #9      _MyHomePageState.initState (package:doi_report/homepage.dart:42:10)
E/flutter (16502): #10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:58)
E/flutter (16502): #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
E/flutter (16502): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (16502): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (16502): #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (16502): #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter (16502): #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
E/flutter (16502): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (16502): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (16502): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #29     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (16502): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #32     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (16502): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (16502): #36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (16502): #37     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter (16502): #38     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
E/flutter (16502): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
E/flutter (16502): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (16502): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (16502): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (16502): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (16502): #44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter (16502): #45     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the server type of authentication, I had windows authentication enable and that was the problem not allowing for my app to reach the data I wanted to retrieve from a php file. although I must say that checking the connectivity and when I was on vpn the result was none made me think that the problem was in the app and not in the server.

it's working with windows authentication disabled but the result of checkconnection is still none.